# React import Jquery-Ui sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have tried to use Jquery-Ui sortable. I did it this way:

```
import React from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';
import sortable from 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/sortable';

class test extends React.Component {
componentDidMount() {
$('.element').sortable();
}
render() {...}
}
```

That works fine but I have one Problem:
I get the warning:
Compiled with warnings.
'sortable' is defined but never used

If I leave out the sortable import it doesnt work.
How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sortable is a plugin for JQuery, then no need import as variable :

```
import sortable from 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/sortable';
```

change to

```
import 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/sortable';
```